# How do I code opposite 'levels' or 'factors' in R

Tags: r

I have  browsed through many different pages on the net but cannot seem to find an answer to this question:

How do I code up equally-opposing levels for use in multiple regression in R?

The only way I can currently see achieving this is to assign the data type to these columns as 'numeric' however I know that this is not an entirely accurate way of doing this as they should ideally be treated as factors.

Essentially what I am looking for is creating 'dummy' variables that are factors rather than numeric.

By way of example, suppose we have a scenario of sporting teams opposing each other, each row assigns a different game where Team A's presence in the game is suggested by the '1' dummy and Team B's presence is '-1' (and all other team's values are obviously set to 0 because they are not playing in this game).

I have attempted to change the data type of these columns to factors, however this results in three levels of 1,0 and -1 but the beta assigned to 1 and -1 is never equally opposite (and in theory the value assigned to 0 should be zero).

Does anybody know how to correctly mathematically and programatically achieve this? Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is Team A the "home" team and Team B the "away" team in your example? Otherwise I can't see how this can work...

Comment: Yes, that is correct, forgot to state that bit! Thanks for asking!